# (Postgres) ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/uuid-ossp": No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, macos, homebrew, psql

I installed curl on my machine today by running `brew install curl`, and it installed curl but also ended up updating a bunch of other packages, including my postgres (I'm using postgresql12)

I end up running any insert statement (which will insert a primary key automatically), and I get this error:

```
[58P01] ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/uuid-ossp": No such file or directory
```

When I run `select * from pg_extension`, I see that I have uuid-ossp installed as an extension, so I do not know why it is not able to find this.

I am using MacOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an answer to my question because I went to a last resort, but I ended up just reinstalling postgres: https://bitadj.medium.com/completely-uninstall-and-reinstall-psql-on-osx-551390904b86

I would still like to hear other answers on the matter, as I would not recommend my answer unless absolutely necessary